# Is it possible to check city based on coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I don't know if this what I want is actually possible but would be gread if it is :)
I have a mobile app that allows user to check-in.
When he do that I need to save it's coordinates in database.
But user must also select and a city where he check-in. I need this because I must list locations by city.
Problem here is that I don't want that user check-in in **London** and select city **Moscow**. City here is very important because I must be sure that location is in that city.
Is there in google api something that is able to detect in what city user is currently 
or anything that can prevent user to make this stupidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in google maps api you have reverse geocoding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: This returns more more results but it doesn't matter to me because all I need is that city name appear in results. Can you tell is this data that google returns always good. I mean is it possible to return two city names based on coordinates or that case is impossible?

Comment: There's going to be a number of results but generally there should also be information on the administrative subdivision responsible for governing the area in which your coordinates fall - and that would usually include the city's name :) As a city cannot belong to two adminstrative subdivisions, the API should never return two distinct names. It could, of course, return multiple levels of administrative subdivisions, e.g. county, province, and country.